# I am getting an error when calling obliqueRF from the obliqueRF package in CRAN, what could it be or how can I look into it more?

Tags: r

***I played around with it for a while and fixed it by changing the data.frame to a matrix****

I loaded up the package and following the function documentation I ran:

```
m.ob = obliqueRF(x=some.data.frame, y=as.factor(some.vector))
tests regularization parameter "lambda" for 10^(c(-5:5)) with separate explicit ridge regressions.
Error in is.nan(as.vector(x)) : 
default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because some.data.frame (I checked) is a data.frame and some.vector is an appropiate vector?

***I played around with it for a while and fixed it by changing the data.frame to a matrix****

Comment: Rather than editing your question, you should post this as an answer (and then accept it) so that it's more easily apparent that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data.frame to a matrix